# How to determine what combination of values in categorical data have the highest success chance

Tags: categorical-data, ordinal-data

I have a dataset with categorical data. Each row of data can be either a success, a failure or neutral. How do I determine what categorical data has a higher chance of producing a success? I'm looking for both single columns (for instance, values a1 and a2 from column A yield a higher chance, with of course some kind of metric like a p-value to determine how certain the success chance is) and combinations (for instance, the combination of a5, b3 and c2 have the highest chance of success).

I already tried some stuff like a chi squared test between the result column and individual columns, and in a column determining which values are different than the rest with a t-test, but I'm not sure if there are other (better) techniques I should be using.

Comment: Can you tell us more context? The success/neutral/failure variable can be seen as ordinal, then you coud use ordinal logistic regression, but to say something more definite we would need more details